# Automatically create App.Config

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013, app-config

Is there any possible way to enable Visual Studio (2013) to automatically create the App.Config file (in the project folder) if it does not exist when building the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I figured out was firstly to create a .bat script that creates the file, and then running it via the "Pre-build event command line" setting under "Build Events" in the projects properties like this:

```
call $(SolutionDir)\CreateAppConfig.bat
```